# nodejs cookbook: node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)

Tags: node.js, gcc, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am installing nodejs through the cookbook https://github.com/redguide/nodejs

and have the following attributes:

```
{
  "nodejs": {
    "version": "0.11.16",
    "engine": "node",
    "install_method": "binary",
    "binary": {
      "checksum": "a1bdc19c779d13b772ac22feead14f592c637ce866d86a59ef225a3273dd7c33"
    },
    "npm_packages": [
      {
        "name": "pm2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

it installs "OK" but issues the error when running node or npm.

```
$node
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)

$ npm
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/node)
```

Is this an error in the cookbook for nodejs OR should I be handling through other measures?  I am new to Chef as of two days ago - just trying to navigate the waters correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error in the cookbook. This looks like [this bug in node](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9079).

Comment: Thanks - I got pretty cought up in the chef stuff.  10.xx worked with the default recipe, Iust figured I was configuring wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on cent OS on my virtual box. I used nvm (Node Version Manager) and installed version 0.12 and it worked.

So I guess it's the version of node.